# Capture camera stream via SDK that requires IntPtr to Window in WPF (without airspace problem)

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, camera, interop

I have an SDK for IP camera and function responsible for start receiving stream requires IntPtr to Window which will be used for display stream. In WPF I am able only to display image on while window, because only Window has Handle in WPF. I tried to open new window and copy content to some control in main window but without big success. Is there any option to for example make dummy IntPtr and somehow get image / stream from it?

```
[DllImport("dhnetsdk.dll")]
    public static extern IntPtr CLIENT_StartRealPlay(IntPtr lLoginID, int nChannelID, IntPtr hWnd, EM_RealPlayType rType, fRealDataCallBackEx cbRealData, fRealPlayDisConnectCallBack cbDisconnect, IntPtr dwUser, uint dwWaitTime);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `System.Windows.Media.Imaging.WriteableBitmap` and pass its IntPtr handle to the camera's SDK call.

Here's an example:

```cs
private void VideoSampleReady(byte[] sample, uint width, uint height, int stride, WriteableBitmap wBmp, System.Windows.Controls.Image dst)
{
    if (sample != null && sample.Length > 0)
    {
        this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
        {
            if (wBmp == null || wBmp.Width != width || wBmp.Height != height)
            {
                wBmp = new WriteableBitmap(
                    (int)width,
                    (int)height,
                    96,
                    96,
                    PixelFormats.Bgr24,
                    null);

                dst.Source = wBmp;
            }

            // Reserve the back buffer for updates.
            wBmp.Lock();

            Marshal.Copy(sample, 0, wBmp.BackBuffer, sample.Length);

            // Specify the area of the bitmap that changed.
            wBmp.AddDirtyRect(new Int32Rect(0, 0, (int)width, (int)height));

            // Release the back buffer and make it available for display.
            wBmp.Unlock();
        }), System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Normal);
    }
}
```

Comment: How to get IntPtr from writeablebitmap and what is "sample" in your example? Now I have something like this and it does not work: 
private IntPtr GetHandle2(int handleNum)
        {
            wBmp = new WriteableBitmap(
            431,
            767,
            96,
            96,
            PixelFormats.Bgr24,
            null);

            wBmp.Lock();
            wBmp.AddDirtyRect(new Int32Rect(0, 0, 431, 767));
            wBmp.Unlock();
            TestImage.Source = wBmp;
            return wBmp.BackBuffer;
        }

Comment: I've added the method signature so you can see how "sample" is defined. The IntPtr is accessible from WriteableBitmap.BackBuffer. You can pass it to your SDK API but you'll most likely need to reserve the memory first by creating the correctly sized WriteableBitmap.

Comment: Seems to your sample method be called repeatedly. Sdk of my camera just starts playing using intptr and I have not any callback when frame is ready so I'm not able to get byte[] and know when to update image source. If I'm just passing backbuffer of writable bitmap, image is just black.

Comment: I know you're using WPF but as a test have you tried creating a new Windows Forms app and passing "this.handle" to your  CLIENT_StartRealPlay function? That's the simplest way to get a window handle I can think of.

Comment: Even in WPF, I can pass handle to whole Window and it works. That I want to acheive is to make it working in WPF app without airspace effect.

Comment: The problems is you can't get window handles for WPF controls in the same way you can for Windows Forms applications. The sample code above is the typical way to do it for WPF. Did you check the pixel format? Your camera may not be returning BGR24 it could be ARGB32 or something else. They will need to match or it won't work.